# Is there a way to get Helium to work on a Moto G7?

Tags: helium

I am trying to restore a single game data file to a new Moto G7 via Helium. I've enabled USB debugging, but when I start the desktop app, they don't connect to each other. The desktop app connects just fine to the old phone I'm trying to pull the data off of.

Comment: Based on your description (which is not very extensive) there seem to be a problem with the connection between your new phone and your PC (Windows, Linux, ...?). Have you checked if `adb shell` or if `adb backup` works on command-line from the desktop PC?

Comment: Yes they did work. Eventually the helium chrome version worked.

Comment: I'd flag for closure as 'ephemeral' but that reason is gone.